# how to use setState() from another class or file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, iso

I would like to change the body of HomeScreen from CustomDialog and it is another class. how can I do this ? I tried it in anyways but I can't do this.

**this is the main file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen(),));

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child:Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text( Global.number.toString() ),
        RaisedButton(child: Text("Click"),
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(context: context,builder: (context){
              return CustomDialog();
            });
          },)
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

**And this is the Another File to Store global variable**

```
class Global {
  static double number = 10.0;
}
```

**And this file is for Dialog**

```
class CustomDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomDialogState createState() => _CustomDialogState();
}

class _CustomDialogState extends State<CustomDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(child: FlatButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add_circle,size: 30,),
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          Global.number++;
        });
      },
    ),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `setState` method of `HomeScreen` down to `CustomDialog`. I have shared a full **working** example based on the code you provided below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen(),));

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  void state() {
    setState((){});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child:Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text( Global.number.toString() ),
        RaisedButton(child: Text("Click"),
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(context: context,builder: (context){
              return CustomDialog(state);
            });
          },)
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class Global {
  static double number = 10.0;
}


class CustomDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function state;
  CustomDialog(this.state);

  @override
  _CustomDialogState createState() => _CustomDialogState();
}

class _CustomDialogState extends State<CustomDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(child: FlatButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add_circle,size: 30,),
      onPressed: (){
          Global.number++;
          widget.state();
      },
    ),);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I create a method parameter for `CustomDialog` and call that method following the change of `Global.number`. I created a wrapper to the `setState` function

```
void state() {
  setState((){});
}
```

in `HomeScreen` and passed that method as the parameter to `CustomDialog`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you help me a lot))

Answer (score -1):

The `state` you `set` in `CustomDialog` is, well... `the state of the dialog`, not of the home screen.

To notify the home screen that some data changed, you can use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to provide this data in a common `super` widget of home screen and the dialog, subscribe the data in the home screen, then access the data in the dialog and change it, then home screen will rebuild automatically.

Please check out [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for more detail.